# Formatting results using SQL select with JET

Tags: sql, select, formatting, oledb, jet

I have data in Excel files that I am pulling out using the [MS JET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) OLEDB provider.  The results of my select are being passed into a component that I cannot change to generate an HTML table on the fly.  Some of my data files contain numbers that I need formatted with commas (#,###).  As I said I cannot change the output component to format the string for me.  Is there a way I can format my results during my select statement?

I have tried a bunch of different things but nothing has worked.

Here is an example select where I need to format enrollment...

```
select
[SCHOOL NAME],
[ENROLLMENT],
[STUDENT / TEACHER RATIO]
from [Public School Districts$]
where [ENROLLMENT]<>null
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your programming environment? That is, what are you using to code the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't try this out right now, but something like

```
FORMAT( [ENROLLMENT], '#,###')
```

should do the trick.

There are a few standard formats that would help you internationalization, but may not give you exactly what you want. Just google `Format Access`.

Comment: There's no ms-access tag on the question, so it's not clear to me that the Access Format() function is available in the environment in which the OP will be running the code.